# Laravel x Cakephp

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou iniciando no Laravel (5.x), porém tenho experiêncian de anos no Cakephp e gostaria de sanar algumas dúvidas, pois não encontrei algo do tipo na Internet:

1) Eu só consigo criar models, controllers e afins pelo comando do Artisan? Ou consigo fazer de outra forma?

2) Afinal, o que é o Artisan e qual sua capacidade (somente criar models e controllers ou tem algo mais)?

3) No Cakephp eu trabalhava com Elements, isto é, pequenos fragmentos de códigos que solicitava na view para compor o layout (p.e.: middle, footer, side bar, menu, breadcrumbs, etc), inclusive no cake existe um Layout default, onde continha header, head, footer e afins, sendo que este layout default não precisava ser "setado" nos controllers, ele já renderiza por padrão. Por fim, as views continham apenas o conteudo/miolo/informações. A dúvida é:

3.1) existe esse Elements no Laravel? Se sim, como faço?
3.2) existe esse layout default para criar as partes comuuns e trabalhar com as views apenas para o miolo/conteúdo?

Por enquanto é só isso de dúvida. Se no Laravel esse contexto de layout não existe, peço a gentileza de me falarem qual seria o melhor caminho para se construir um Layout flexível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Não! O artisan é apenas um agregador de comandos que ajudam você em algumas tarefas do projeto. [Veja mais](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan).
2. Como dito no tópico 1, o artisan é um agregador de comandos. Você pode usá-lo para criar partes da sua aplicação e fazer outras tarefas, como limpar o cache da aplicação, efetuar migrações para o banco de dados, dentre outras. Você também pode criar comandos personalizados com ele. [Mais informações sobre o artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#introduction).
3. O Laravel não provê **nativamente** algo como os *elements* que existem no CakePHP, porém, ele vem com um sistema de template chamado [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) onde você pode criar seus próprios "*elements*" e fazer templates bem flexíveis.

Como um material de apoio (muito bom), você pode ver as [videoaulas do Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals) com os seus fundamentos. Vai te esclarecer bastante algumas dúvidas sobre todas essas questões que você levantou além de ensinar a fazer algumas aplicações simples.

Comment: Muito bom chorajunior. Obrigado, mto esclarecedor